# logstash : basic http request to a web api

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am a newbie in logstash and i just want to make a basic http get to a simple api and display result in console

my conf file named "api.conf" contain :

```
input {
  http {
    url  => 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums' 
  }
}
output {
     stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

and i launch it from logstash folder  i have just dowloaded and have not changed thanks a windos cmd command:

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\logstash-6.2.2>.\bin\logstash.bat -f .\api.conf
```

it returning n error in console:
Failed to execute action

> {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, 
>   :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError",  :message=>"Something is
>   wrong with your configuration.", 
>   :backtrace=>["C:/Users/username/Desktop/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb:89:in
>   `config_init'", 
>   "C:/Users/username/Desktop/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/inputs/base.rb:62:in`
>   initialize'", 
>   "C:/Users/username/Desktop/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugins/plugin_factory.rb:89:in
>   `plugin'",
>
>   "C:/Users/username/Desktop/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:112:in`
>   plugin'",   "(eval):8:in `<eval>'", "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:994:in`
>   eval'",
>   "C:/Users/username/Desktop/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:84:in
>   `initialize'",
>
>   "C:/Users/username/Desktop/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:169:in`
>   initialize'",
>   "C:/Users/username/Desktop/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:40:in
>   `execute'",
>
>   "C:/Users/username/Desktop/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:315:in`
>   block in converge_state'",
>   "C:/Users/username/Desktop/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141:in
>   `with_pipelines'",
>
>   "C:/Users/username/Desktop/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:312:in`
>   block in converge_state'",   "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in
>   `each'", 
>   "C:/Users/username/Desktop/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:299:in`
>   converge_state'",
>   "C:/Users/username/Desktop/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:166:in
>   `block in converge_state_and_update'",
>
>   "C:/Users/username/Desktop/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141:in`
>   with_pipelines'",
>   "C:/Users/username/Desktop/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:164:in
>   `converge_state_and_update'",
>
>   "C:/Users/username/Desktop/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:90:in`
>   execute'",
>   "C:/Users/username/Desktop/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:348:in
>   `block in execute'",
>
>   "C:/Users/username/Desktop/logstash-6.2.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:24:in`
>   block in initialize'"]}

Do you know what I am dig wrong and how make it working?

Answer (score 1):

For pulling web rest api, the correct input plug-in is http_poller

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
     test1 => "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums"
    }
    request_timeout => 60
    # Supports "cron", "every", "at" and "in" schedules by rufus scheduler
    schedule => { cron => "* * * * * UTC"}
    codec => "json"
    # A hash of request metadata info (timing, response headers, etc.) will be sent here
    metadata_target => "http_poller_metadata"
  }
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```